# Need help processing (not executing) javascript found on the page

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I need to drive a website that is rendered almost entirely with javascript.  I have been able to detect the rendered page and navigate it so far, however there are variables in the script that I'd like to process for some navigation decisions.  I can identify tags using xpath but I can't get the text in between them.  To be clear, I do not wish to execute javascript, just read the variables in the javascript on the page.  I'm having trouble finding any documentation that spells out what I need.  In one thread someone mentioned using a document object, but I'm not sure how to programatically get to that.

I'd really appreciate a hint here.  Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  WebDriver.getPageSource().  Since there were no parsers javascript I located the bits I wanted with a regular expression then converted the JSON into an object with simple json.

```
    private String getRandomProvider(){
    String shortName = "";
    JSONArray providers;
    String page = this.getPageSource();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("domainBootstrap\\.providers = (\\[,?\\{.*\\}\\]);");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(page);
    if (matcher.find()){
        try {
            providers = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(matcher.group(1));
            int randomProvider = (int)(Math.random() * providers.size());
            JSONObject provider = (JSONObject) providers.get(randomProvider);
            shortName = provider.get("shortName").toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return shortName;
```